# How create regex that forbid special symbols and allows max 15 chars?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 regexp, first one forbid all special symbols and second allow only 15 chars, but how to combine it together in 1 regexp with replace?

**Example:**

```
const first = '1222-222-22222277777777'.replace(/^(.{15}).+/, '$1')

const second = '1222-222-22222277777777'.replace(/(?<!^\+)\+|[^\d+]+/g, '')
```

**Expected result:**

```
'122222222222277'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would challenge the idea of limiting the length of a string with RegExp to begin with; once you've replaced the "*special symbols*", use `String.slice()` instead - [it's ***loads*** faster (~70% so in Chrome on macOS)](https://jsbench.me/e1le7cdlls/1):

```js
console.log('1222-222-22222277777777'.replace(/(?<!^\+)\+|[^\d+]+/g, '').slice(0, 15));
```